# AngularJs filtering on grouped elements and pagination

Tags: angularjs

I have a grouped elements that want filter based on a search box. The filter works, but I have problem with the pagination, that show white page for page that not contains element filtered. When I'm on page 1 and search for element that is on page 2 the page one remains white and I should switch to page 2 manually.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/qyb6N/9/

```
// create a deferred object to be resolved later
var teamsDeferred = $q.defer();

// return a promise. The promise says, "I promise that I'll give you your
// data as soon as I have it (which is when I am resolved)".
$scope.teams = teamsDeferred.promise;

// create a list of unique teams
var uniqueTeams = unique($scope.players, 'team');

// resolve the deferred object with the unique teams
// this will trigger an update on the view
teamsDeferred.resolve(uniqueTeams);

// function that takes an array of objects
// and returns an array of unique valued in the object
// array for a given key.
// this really belongs in a service, not the global window scope
function unique(data, key) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var value = data[i][key];
        if (result.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    console.log(result)
    console.log(Math.ceil(result.length / 10))
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil(result.length / 10);
    return result;
}

$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.pageSize = 5;
$scope.maxSize = 2;
```

[EDIT]

I created a function to watch for search input change:

```
$scope.$watch('searchInput', function () {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.teams = $filter('filter')($scope.teams, $scope.searchInput);
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.teams.length / $scope.pageSize);
});
```

Comment: The filter is applied to filter teams not players.

Comment: Yes because I want filter the teams and the players. If I add filter to both I got a different problem, all teams are showned and only the filtered elements have the players. I was thinking to create a function that watch and update the teams...

Comment: Yeah, you need a custom function if you want to filter teams OR pleyers

Comment: But the problem is with the pagination, not with the filter. I update the answer with my watcher funtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the sequence of the filter. Let's say you want to filter the *team*, then you need to apply the search filter ***before*** the pagination filters.

```
<div ng-repeat="team in teams | filter:searchInput | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*pageSize  | limitTo:pageSize">
```

Comment: Ah, now it seems ok, I've changed the order of the filter and also added a watch function to update the pagination number. Thanks a lot!!!